# Sketching fuctions - standard meaning of terms?

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

When sketching the graphs of polynomials, do certain terms always have the same meaning?

For example, in $f(x) = x^n + c$, the intersection with the y-axis is always $c$, no matter how high the degree of the polynomial (because $c$ is a constant of course). But I was wondering whether or not for example $x^1$ or $x^2$ and so forth also always have a certain 'effect' on a function, which would make sketching them easier.

Comment: I am guessing that you want to know the differences between the graphs of the functions, $y=x^0=1,y=x^1=x,y=x^2,y=x^3\cdots y=x^n$?

Answer (score -1):

The highest-order term of a polynomial always determines its general behavior very far from the origin. Low-order terms always are good estimates sufficiently close to the origin.

Comment: What about $1/x^n + c$? I'm sure there are dozens more examples.

Comment: @user14445, if $n$ is positive, then $1/x^n+c$ is not a polynomial!

Comment: Ahh, ok; I didn't downvote your answer btw, someone else did.